# HyperLink in word table

Tags: visual-foxpro, word-automation

How do I in word automation, in a table cell, put a line into a hyperlink ?
Original:
.cell[1,1].Range.InsertAfter( link )

Wrong:
.cell[1,1].range.InsertAfter( oDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(oRange,link,,,link) )

Am I missing to define oRange here ?

Comment: Looks to me like Hyperlinks.Add converts an existing range to a hyperlink. So you need to fill the cell first, then turn it into a range, and then make it into a hyperlink.

Comment: got it. after setting the cell range to object, finally the link appear in the cell.